# How to build scikit-image in travis-ci?

Tags: python, travis-ci, scikit-image

I am trying to build a script that makes use of `scikit-image` on `Travis-ci`. It complains that `six` is not up to date. Just to be sure, I tried to replicate the .travis.yml of the scikit-image project on github, but it did nothing to change the situation. I also tried to update `six`, but to no avail...

Does someone know how to build scikit-image on travis?

My requirements.txt:

```
# Requirements list:
scikit-image
```

My trace:

```
$ source ~/virtualenv/python3.3/bin/activate

$ python --version

Python 3.3.5

$ pip --version

pip 6.0.7 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.3.5/lib/python3.3/site-packages (python 3.3)

5.80s$ pip install -r requirements.txt

You are using pip version 6.0.7, however version 6.0.8 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Collecting scikit-image (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))

Downloading scikit-image-0.10.1.tar.gz (16.7MB)

100% |################################| 16.7MB 20kB/s

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build-wsd_vd/scikit-image/setup.py", line 110, in <module>

check_requirements()

File "/tmp/pip-build-wsd_vd/scikit-image/setup.py", line 105, in check_requirements

% ((package_name, ) + min_version))

ImportError: You need `six` version 1.3 or later.

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build-wsd_vd/scikit-image/setup.py", line 110, in <module>

check_requirements()

File "/tmp/pip-build-wsd_vd/scikit-image/setup.py", line 105, in check_requirements

% ((package_name, ) + min_version))

ImportError: You need `six` version 1.3 or later.

----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wsd_vd/scikit-image

The command "pip install -r requirements.txt" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the line `pip install six>=1.3` to your install or before_install section?  To be clear, a separate line (before your `pip install -r requirements.txt` or whatever)

Comment: And can you include your entire .travis.yml file here please

Comment: @Dannnno I tried to put a pip install six --upgrade command into the `install` section, which failed. But using `pip install six>=1.3` in the `before_install` section works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an error that a specific dependency isn't being met, being more specific about that dependency usually helps.  I like to put dependencies that I don't directly use in a `before_install` section.

```
before_install:
    pip install six>=1.3
install:
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

pip allows you to specify constraints on the versions of packages you install. If you had to use 1.3 exactly you could use `==`.